# How to properly convert xsd:dateTime to date in europe?

Tags: java, time, timezone

I have the following date a source: `2013-11-07T08:35:00.000+01:00` which is an `xsd:dateTime` from XML request.

I'd like to convert it to `DDMMYYYHH:mm` with respect to Central European Time (CET), so that the final date is displayed to someone in Germany according to his local time.

How could I do this best?

I started to convert the string source to a Calendar date:

`Calendar cal = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(date)`

But how could I continue to get the desired String format with respect to the timezone?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: check this javadoc

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html

Comment: yes I have, edited above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime("2013-11-07T08:35:00.000+01:00");
DateTime dtGermany = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.mediumDateTime().withLocale(Locale.GERMANY);
String s = fmt.print(dtGermany);
```

Comment: This gives: `07.11.2013 08:35:00`, but: isn't this the wrong time? Shouldn't it respect the daylight saving offset (which is GMT+2 at the moment for CET)?

Comment: Shouldn't I be getting 09:35:00?

Comment: On November 7th, the date you gave it, DST is over and Germany is at GMT+1.  [See here for details](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=37&year=2013).

Answer (score 0):

Do it in three steps:

- Use the usual techniques to convert the field to a `XMLGregorianCalendar` object.
- Call `toGregorianCalendar(TimeZone, Locale, XMLGregorianCalendar)` on it.
- Use the appropriate German `DateFormqat`.